# Utilising LibVLC MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached to reset MediaPlayer when playback finishes

Tags: android, libvlc

I'm in the process of writing an Android app activity that houses a **LibVLC MediaPlayer** implementation. The `MediaPlayer` works fine for the most part, however upon video conclusion, the `MediaPlayer` will become unresponsive. *From my research, it looks like this could be because the Media is getting unset upon `MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached` firing ([vajehu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361153/libvlc-media-player-end-reached-weird-behavior)).*

I've been keeping an eye on `MediaPlayer.getPlaybackState()` and can see that the `MediaPlayer` object is sitting in the *"Ended"* state when playback concludes, as expected.

I can go ahead and release my `MediaPlayer` and re-create it when `MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached` is fired, but am unsure if this is a good course of action. I am hoping to have the `MediaPlayer` move back to the beginning of the video and await user input to commence playback again.

(In case it's pertinent - I'm utilising [MrMaffen's vlc-android-sdk](https://github.com/mrmaffen/vlc-android-sdk)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've since discovered a neat and tidy (and more importantly *efficient*!) solution for this;

Upon `MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached` firing I:

- Call `MediaPlayer.setMedia(media)` to reload the `Media` object
- Reset a few UI elements relating to my `MediaPlayer`
- Finally I set the `MediaPlayer` position to the start of the `Media` object with `MediaPlayer.setTime(0)`

**Side note:** since LibVLC's `MediaPlayer.setTime(Long position)` method doesn't have an effect unless the `MediaPlayer.isPlaying()`, I needed to write a small wrapper method to asynchronously:

- `MediaPlayer.play()` and wait for `MediaPlayer.isPlaying()`
- Then `MediaPlayer.setTime(0)`
- Finally `MediaPlayer.pause()`

A *much* simpler solution than I expected, though I hope this helps anyone who might be scratching their head whilst working on the same type of project.